# change tsibble frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, tsibble

I have a dataframe from 2012 to 2018 (first 200 rows below) and I am trying to transform it into a tsibble. Although I have already managed to transform it, using the UI variable as key and the Date variable as index, I had some troubles with my analyses due to the frequency. I have daily data so the frequency on the tsibble is [1D], but I need to have the frequency by year in order to analyse the seasonality. I tried to use the years(Ano) as the index but then everything after was wrong. Do I have a solution for this problem? I tried the following function too but it didn't work:

https://rdrr.io/github/dashfordgroup/tsibbletools/man/change_frequency.html

```
structure(list(Dia = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18), Mes = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), Ano = c(2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012), UI = c(18.0647497177124, 51.0355095863342, 47.5402774810791, 
340.893737792969, 247.539836883545, 399.510726928711, 122.39359664917, 
98.836296081543, 35.0952081680298, 50.6278982162476, 87.2319049835205, 
77.6166572570801, 112.672420501709, 2.67568874359131, -392.484573364258, 
618.681500434875, 692.416625976562, 236.788291931152, 51.255313873291, 
71.8802337646484, 345.232437133789, 236.85432434082, -0.00471636652946472, 
-27.9389114379883, 146.920881986618, 341.540222167969, 1208.46826171875, 
454.171142578125, 94.2786865234375, -23.250904083252, 6.60693836212158, 
11.3990550041199, 461.585052490234, 110.249738693237, 282.145706176758, 
30.0083067417145, 922.615142822266, 665.348541259766, 280.90966796875, 
129.148958206177, 97.8483505249023, 151.280666351318, 41.1154479980469, 
462.513458251953, 223.375587463379, 243.899364471436, 91.236083984375, 
-33.4530096054077, 419.289459228516, 216.38060760498, 223.88525390625, 
42.9771499633789, 63.462251663208, 135.543815612793, 103.11067199707, 
-2.97302103042603, 50.1539402008057, 31.7654695510864, 4.74521112442017, 
116.475090026855, -31.0308532714844, 95.1957511901855, -74.0424919128418, 
74.0312874317169, 370.580841064453, 439.345306396484, 288.222801208496, 
245.310737609863, 163.978561401367, -43.6043725013733, 90.422176361084, 
13.5707854032516, 35.8152360916138, -251.285369873047, -396.40592956543, 
27.4398317337036, 119.581299781799, 374.314788818359, 895.551239013672, 
583.116119384766, 83.0863494873047, -162.666477203369, -326.430221557617, 
-219.034694671631, 246.566764831543, 142.276351928711, 167.783622741699, 
116.547183990479, -962.846618652344, -199.737373352051, 581.776489257812, 
127.202213287354, 243.02904510498, 546.869003295898, 322.698364257812, 
416.055419921875, -35.2042512893677, 4.76407432556152, 59.2325496673584, 
109.642734527588, 39.2587299346924, 70.3620586395264, 3161.94677734375, 
1006.70434570312, 2140.01275634766, 2786.77355957031, 1705.16961669922, 
944.830413818359, 655.952301025391, 338.197479248047, 63.7034378051758, 
519.655364990234, 658.758819580078, 443.135345458984, 365.920120239258, 
-533.251229286194, 514.586601257324, 67.87255859375, -295.31233215332, 
175.399646759033, 27.4736328125, -3460.8505859375, -2083.35198974609, 
-1276.77111816406, -203.34831237793, 121.706581115723, -1469.41851806641, 
-224.111042022705, 191.504776000977, 172.109447479248, 26.7028465270996, 
113.872447013855, 115.648100852966, 365.883389472961, 2044.16656494141, 
-32.7207946777344, 24.2001395225525, 1416.10055541992, -49.864501953125, 
953.696166992188, 1353.91192626953, 331.314163208008, 755.130172729492, 
504.707885742188, 1100.87829589844, 410.127822875977, 1059.75042724609, 
1814.80114746094, 732.802597045898, 2145.48461914062, 2912.95367431641, 
210.142471313477, 39.4968557357788, 380.054672241211, 278.151397705078, 
1334.32025146484, 681.097854614258, -69.2400665283203, 567.077270507812, 
624.232055664062, 391.584182739258, 586.699615478516, 1279.32067871094, 
3932.2900390625, 789.148895263672, 474.529556274414, 316.368942260742, 
589.92162322998, 107.363967418671, 3477.34375, 241.996397972107, 
350.299514770508, 3326.77624511719, 2569.17126464844, 4582.50708007812, 
1923.22076416016, -61.1435556411743, -85.2687129974365, 217.463203430176, 
517.184478759766, 172.391616821289, 1056.78869628906, 2622.95007324219, 
2552.87609863281, 1118.66555786133, 1658.28143310547, 1830.66302490234, 
1645.97857666016, 874.851470947266, 1195.69207763672, 771.39143371582, 
1265.49255371094, 1729.88415527344, 4629.59558105469, 3249.35119628906, 
2862.19885253906, 2368.9833984375, 380.631881713867, 276.73908996582, 
5071.85693359375), Date = structure(c(1325376000, 1325462400, 
1325548800, 1325635200, 1325721600, 1325808000, 1325894400, 1325980800, 
1326067200, 1326153600, 1326240000, 1326326400, 1326412800, 1326499200, 
1326585600, 1326672000, 1326758400, 1326844800, 1326931200, 1327017600, 
1327104000, 1327190400, 1327276800, 1327363200, 1327449600, 1327536000, 
1327622400, 1327708800, 1327795200, 1327881600, 1327968000, 1328054400, 
1328140800, 1328227200, 1328313600, 1328400000, 1328486400, 1328572800, 
1328659200, 1328745600, 1328832000, 1328918400, 1329004800, 1329091200, 
1329177600, 1329264000, 1329350400, 1329436800, 1329523200, 1329609600, 
1329696000, 1329782400, 1329868800, 1329955200, 1330041600, 1330128000, 
1330214400, 1330300800, 1330387200, 1330473600, 1330560000, 1330646400, 
1330732800, 1330819200, 1330905600, 1330992000, 1331078400, 1331164800, 
1331251200, 1331337600, 1331424000, 1331510400, 1331596800, 1331683200, 
1331769600, 1331856000, 1331942400, 1332028800, 1332115200, 1332201600, 
1332288000, 1332374400, 1332460800, 1332547200, 1332633600, 1332720000, 
1332806400, 1332892800, 1332979200, 1333065600, 1333152000, 1333238400, 
1333324800, 1333411200, 1333497600, 1333584000, 1333670400, 1333756800, 
1333843200, 1333929600, 1334016000, 1334102400, 1334188800, 1334275200, 
1334361600, 1334448000, 1334534400, 1334620800, 1334707200, 1334793600, 
1334880000, 1334966400, 1335052800, 1335139200, 1335225600, 1335312000, 
1335398400, 1335484800, 1335571200, 1335657600, 1335744000, 1335830400, 
1335916800, 1336003200, 1336089600, 1336176000, 1336262400, 1336348800, 
1336435200, 1336521600, 1336608000, 1336694400, 1336780800, 1336867200, 
1336953600, 1337040000, 1337126400, 1337212800, 1337299200, 1337385600, 
1337472000, 1337558400, 1337644800, 1337731200, 1337817600, 1337904000, 
1337990400, 1338076800, 1338163200, 1338249600, 1338336000, 1338422400, 
1338508800, 1338595200, 1338681600, 1338768000, 1338854400, 1338940800, 
1339027200, 1339113600, 1339200000, 1339286400, 1339372800, 1339459200, 
1339545600, 1339632000, 1339718400, 1339804800, 1339891200, 1339977600, 
1340064000, 1340150400, 1340236800, 1340323200, 1340409600, 1340496000, 
1340582400, 1340668800, 1340755200, 1340841600, 1340928000, 1341014400, 
1341100800, 1341187200, 1341273600, 1341360000, 1341446400, 1341532800, 
1341619200, 1341705600, 1341792000, 1341878400, 1341964800, 1342051200, 
1342137600, 1342224000, 1342310400, 1342396800, 1342483200, 1342569600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide more of a description for what you want to achieve. The frequency (usually referred to as 'interval' in the documentation) of 1 day is appropriate for of this dataset. You can use this data to explore the seasonal period of 1 year using functions for visualising, modelling or otherwise exploring the data. Typically this is done by some option for setting the seasonal period, such as `period = "1 year"`.

Comment: Hello Mitchell! I actually emailed you today talking about this problem!